# I'm receiving a "compile error: Can't assign to read-only property" I am not sure what the issue is, can anyone see the problem? seems to be line 6

Tags: excel, vba, automation

```
With wsData

LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row  
LastColumn = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set DataRange = .Range(Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)) 

Set wsPT = wb.Worksheets.Add 

wsPT.Name = "Pivot Table" 

Set PTCache = wb.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, DataRange)
```

The Error seems to be showing for the "Name" on line 5

Comment: Please show the complete code. I do not see any error in your code.

Comment: Did you use `Dim wsPT As Worksheet` before assining it to new worksheet?
Second option is issue with `wb` I assume it means ThisWorkbook (the one with macro), not ActiveWrokbook (the one in which macro is beeing run). It can make a difference if you have at least 2 workbooks opened and switching between them (even unintenditionally).

Comment: not this error but will be, you are missing a `.` in front of the first `Cells` in this line: `Set DataRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))`

Comment: `wsPT` should be a worksheet. It would yell at you during run-time for trying a type mismatch, but the `.name` property of a workbook is read-only (You need to saveas to change the name of a workbook) and the compiler is catching it.

Comment: I applied Dim wsPT As Worksheet at the beginning,  Where would you suggest I write this after assigning to new worksheet?

Comment: No you need to change the dim statement. Instead of `Dim wsPT as Workbook` it should be `Dim wsPT as worksheet`. That's all you need to do to clear this error, though you should definitely follow Scott Craner's advice (add a `.` to the cell) because how it is now will bite you sooner or later.

Comment: So would I need to replace Name to worksheet? I’m a beginner so I’m not too familiar with this at all.